# Angular 2: ngfor with ngmodel gets wrong value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following (simplified) template:

```
<div *ngFor="let input of inputs; let in=index">
                value: {{inputs[in].event.value}}
                        <div [ngSwitch]="input.event.type">
                            <input *ngSwitchCase="'java.lang.String'" type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputs[in].event.value">
      </div>
```

I have also tried: `[(ngModel)]="input.event.value"`.

The value set on the input is that of the last iterator variable on all inputs rendered, though the value is correct, something like:

```
value: first value
<select value="first value"></select>
value: second value
<select value="first value"></select>
value: third value
<select value="first value"></select>
```

If I bind to the input element with value: `value="{{ input.event.value }}"`, then the value is correct.

Comment: I had similar issue [in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265761/using-ngfor-with-ngmodel-dynamic-data-wrong-behaviour) And given answer solved this problem- add  `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

Answer (score 6):

I was not setting the `name` field on the input element correctly, and that was apparently causing this.

Comment: This is the same issue that I ran across.  I was working with some legacy code, the name was assigned like this:
`name="'exampleNameHere-' + exampleObject.ID"`
Changing it to `name="exampleNameHere-{{exampleObject.ID}}"` solved the issue.

Comment: Thankyou so much !! Been banging my head for 14 hours

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to bind like this:

```
value="{{ input.event.value }}"
```

Correct way in Angular2:

```
[value]="input.event.value"
```

Try this:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'java.lang.String'" type="text" [value]="input.event.value">
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried using indexes to see if it would work correctly, using ` [(ngModel)]="input.event.value">` has same effect.

Comment: Have you tried 

<input *ngSwitchCase="'java.lang.String'" type="text" [value]="input.event.value">

Comment: I need two-way binding... I don't think [value] does that?