# Using ngFor with ngModel dynamic data wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular2-forms

I have complex and probably rookie bug in logic of my application, so I'll try to give comprehensive amount of information.

I have registration form binded to my data model. Phone number fields can be added by user during registration and saved as array.

My model:

```
export class RegistrationFormModel {
  //
  //
    Phones: Array<{Phone: string;}>;
  //
  //
}
```

And representation of this part of form

```
     <ion-item *ngFor="let Phone of regModel.Phones; let i = index">

        <ion-label floating>Phone number*</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" required [(ngModel)]="regModel.Phones[i].Phone" name="Phone" #Phone="ngModel"
                   pattern="\d{10}"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon *ngIf="i==0" name="ios-add-circle-outline" item-right no-padding
                  (click)="addPhone()"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon *ngIf="i!=0" name="ios-remove-circle-outline" item-right no-padding
                  (click)="removePhone(i)"></ion-icon>

     </ion-item>
```

My methods for adding and removing phones. I added logs and incremental index for debug purposes:

```
debugIndex = 0;
 \\
 \\
  addPhone() {
    console.log('phones before add: ' + JSON.stringify(this.regModel.Phones));
    this.regModel.Phones.splice((this.regModel.Phones.length), 0, {Phone: '' + this.debugIndex++});
    console.log('phones after add: ' + JSON.stringify(this.regModel.Phones));
  }

  removePhone(i: number) {
    console.log('phones before delete: ' + JSON.stringify(this.regModel.Phones));
    this.regModel.Phones.splice(i, 1);
    console.log('phones after delete: ' + JSON.stringify(this.regModel.Phones));
  }
```

And from this part strange things happen. According to logs data writes in my model properly but in UI last element replaces everything in input fields. **But after removing one of the phones displayed phones for this moment seems like represent last state of UI.**

[image]

My logs captured during recording:

```
 "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456789"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"0"}]", 
  "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"},{"Phone":"1"}]", 
  "phones before delete: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"},{"Phone":"1"}]", 
  "phones after delete: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"}]", 
  "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456789"},{"Phone":"4567890"},{"Phone":"2"}]", 
  "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"4567890"},{"Phone":"2"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"4567890"},{"Phone":"2"},{"Phone":"3"}]", 
  "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"2"},{"Phone":"3"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"2"},{"Phone":"3"},{"Phone":"4"}]", 
  "phones before delete: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"2"},{"Phone":"3"},{"Phone":"4"}]"
  "phones after delete: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"2"},{"Phone":"4"}]", 
  "phones before add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"47890"},{"Phone":"4"}]", 
  "phones after add: [{"Phone":"123456"},{"Phone":"456789"},{"Phone":"47890"},{"Phone":"4"},{"Phone":"5"}]"
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to your input should fix the problem:

```
<ion-input type="tel" required [(ngModel)]="regModel.Phones[i].Phone" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} #Phone="ngModel" pattern="\d{10}">
</ion-input>
```

For every input with `NgModel` directive, `FormControl` will be created and it will be added to `FormGroup`, but when you add `standalone: true`, the fields won't be added to the `FormGroup` and this problem should be fixed. You should also remove `name` attribute from your input because only one of those is needed when using template driven forms. (`name` or `standalone: true`)

Comment: If you remove the fields from the FormGroup by adding "standalone: true". How do you use the built in Form validation?